# SQL: Query adjacent nodes in a directed graph

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a graph with nodes `{A, B, C, D, ...}` and a table which specifies the directed edges between them.

```
| node_1 | node_2 |
|-----------------|
|      A | B      |
|      A | C      |
|      B | A      |
|      B | D      |
|      D | A      |
```

We write `A ~ B` if there is an edge from `A` to `B`. So a row where `node_1 = A` and `node_2 = B` implies `A ~ B`. I distinguish between the following types of relations:

```
A = B if A ~ B and B ~ A
A > B if A ~ B and not B ~ A
A < B if B ~ A and not A ~ B
```

How can I retrieve all the nodes adjacent to a given node along with their type of relation? For example, a query for `A` on the above table should return

```
| node | type |
|------|------|
|    B | =    | (because A ~ B and B ~ A)
|    C | >    | (because A ~ C and not C ~ A)
|    D | <    | (because D ~ A and not A ~ D)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Hi, could you please include the code that you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way :

```
select node, 
       case when count(*) = 2       then '=' 
            when max(ordertype) = 1 then '>'
            when max(ordertype) = 2 then '<' end as type
from (select node2 node,
             1 ordertype 
      from nodes 
      where node1 = 'A'
      union all 
      select node1, 
             2 
      from nodes 
      where node2 = 'A') t 
group by node 
order by node
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . you can use conditional logic with aggregation:

```
select (case when node_1 = 'A' then node_2 else node_1 end) as other_node,
       (case when count(*) = 2 then '='
             when max(node_1) = 'A' then '>'
             else '<'
        end) as type
from nodes n
where 'A' in (node_1, node_2)
group by (case when node_1 = 'A' then node_2 else node_1 end);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67746558/sql-query-adjacent-nodes-in-a-directed-graph/67746658#67746658) is a db<>fiddle.

This seems like the simplest and probably the most performant solution.